# How is it that other computers can access a computer but not the other way round?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a residential network on all my computers with windows 7. I just bought a new one. I join the network of a residential group.

But I cannot access any computer, whereas others can access one another and that one.

Error is always 0x80070035, I've read all threads on the subject elsewhere, now I post here maybe someone knows better.

Comment: Do the other computers all appear in your "network" folder?

Comment: Have you tried disabling all firewalls and anti-virus/internet-security software?  After reading all those other threads, what did they lead you to attempt already?

Comment: I've had this problem too. Even with all firewalls disabled on all computers in the network, I still couldn't. I eventually just gave up on it, and my friend and I just use skype to transfer files.